# Unnest string array and transpose in Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Bigquery, I've a table A with string array and I need to cast to int64/string ( if possible ) so I can join with table B which of Int64/string

The main ask here is:

I've a table A,  where I've string array mapped with Ref ID as below:

[image]

I'm trying to get unnest and my desired output should be as below.

[image]

I did tried below script:

```
SELECT a0_string_arrat,
ref_id
FROM TableA AS t,
  t.String_array AS a0_String_array
```

But the challenge with above script is, I've close to 1000 Ref IDs, but my output is resulting only 100

If I try the below, I'm able to get all 1000 rows.

```
SELECT string_array,
ref_id
FROM TableA
```

The end goal is to I need to unnest and cast to Int64/string.  The above script is not working for my need. can someone help on this.

Comment: It seems your first query is exactly what you want for your expected output.  Would you double-check if it really output only 100 rows despite having actual 1000 rows without **LIMIT 100** ?  And for casting into **INT64**,  **CAST(a0_string_arrat AS INT64) AS int_id** would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CROSS JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross_join) + [UNNEST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) in order to get the values from the array attributed to each `ref_id`:

```sql
select
  ref_id,
  unnested_numbers
from tablea
cross join unnest(string_array) as unnested_numbers
order by 2, 1
```

This should give you the desired output that you specified.